Error while implementing Google Map Auto Complete Places in flutter
I was trying to implement Google Map auto complete places in my flutter web app but I am getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest error.

Here is my networkUtil code:
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NetworkUtils {
  static Future<String?> fetchUrl(Uri uri,
      {Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log('error in network utils: $e');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

I am calling it in my controller
void placeAutoComplete(String query) async {
    Uri uri =
        Uri.https("maps.googleapis.com", "maps/api/place/autocomplete/json", {
      "input": query,
      "Key": ApiConstant.cSecretApiKey,
    });
    String? response = await NetworkUtils.fetchUrl(uri);
    if (response != null) {
      log(response);
    }
  }

and I am calling placeAutoComplete function when a button is pressed to check
  ontap: () {
        controller.placeAutoComplete('Dubai');
        }

EDITED
class NetworkUtils {
  static Future<String?> fetchUrl(Uri uri,
      {Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
    try {
      print('uri: ${uri.toString()}');
      final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
      log('response: ${response.toString()}');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log('error in network utils: $e');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

i tried to print the uri and it gives me the link to the json file which contains the prediction so the problem is from this line of code is it because the header is null? if so how to fix it
final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);

i tried everything but none of them worked.


The error should have more details than just then name of the error, eg was it 404 error? 500? etc. 2. You are using "Key" but it should be "key"


nothing it's just saying XMLHttpRequest error
the problem is with this code final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
is it because the header is null? is so what should i add

When I run that code on my PC I get a json response, no errors. When I run it in dartpad I get XMLHttpRequest. I didn't notice you mentioned this was for a web app. If you check the developer tools you'll see there is errors in the network tab related to CORS Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Dubai&Key=YOUR_API_KEY. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.  cont...

You shouldn't be using the API key directly in your app. You should have your own serverside code that makes the request to the google API, and your web app should make the request to your server. So your API key is never exposed to the app clients, and you avoid the issue of CORS in the browser (your serverside code is not restricted to obey CORS).
